# Grouping a list of objects into a list of lists by a boolean function using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a list of objects. I want to group them into a list of lists where each inner list contains elements for which a boolean comparison function returns `true`:

```java
public class VO {
    public VO(int age, int val) {
        this.age = age;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int age;
    public int val;
}

public void testGrouping() {
    // Equal to vo2
    VO vo1 = new VO(1, 100);
    // Equal to vo1 and vo3
    VO vo2 = new VO(3, 105);
    // Equal to vo2 but not vo1 (age difference > 2),
    // so it belongs into a new bucket
    VO vo3 = new VO(5, 110);
    // Equal to vo3, so it belongs into the same bucket as vo3
    VO vo4 = new VO(7, 116);

    List<VO> values = Arrays.asList(vo1, vo2, vo3, vo4);

    //Group values using isEqual(VO, VO) into buckets somehow
    //Any two values in a bucket must pass the check

    //Expected without any specific order:
    //[[vo1, vo2, [vo3, vo4]]
}

private boolean isEqual(VO a, VO b) {
    return Math.abs(a.age - b.age) <= 2 && Math.abs(a.val - b.val) <= 10;
}
```

This is just a simplified example of the data that I have, in reality the comparison method is more complicated than that. Important is that each object must match each other object in its bucket regarding the check. The objects cannot be grouped/mapped by a specific value.

I already have code which does this but takes three levels of for-loops and which took me about a day to write. I'm curious if this can be achieved easier with streams.

Comment: This is an unsolvable task as the criteria is not guaranteeing to produce distinct groups. You can have three elements, `a`, `b`, `c`, for which the distance between `a` and `b` is small enough to belong to one group, same for `b` and `c`, while `a` and `c` are not close enough. What then?

Comment: I currently iterate over the list which is sorted by size first. I'm looking for an approach that is "good enough", so having [a,b] and [c] is as valid as having [a] and [b,c].

Comment: That’s not how the Stream API works. Just keep your loop…

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping your items first, then use `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```
values.stream().map(name -> name.split("\\s+")).collect(groupingBy(a -> a[1]));
```

This does not return lists but arrays - but the concept is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote, the comparison method is more complicated than that. It's not possible to map the values by a simple method. They have different numeric values which are compared and must not exceed a certain difference.

Comment: I don't think you can write a one-liner using the Stream API. Give this a try: First, sort your list using a `Comparator` which returns 0 only if your grouping condition is fulfilled. The result should be a list where all items that are in a group are consecutive. Second, iterate over the list using a for-loop and use the same Comparator to detect the group edges (start a new group every time comparing the previous and the current element returns <> 0). Not what you wanted, but maybe more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a bit the `isEqual` method so that you can use it as a comparator for the [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)). Then you can collect the `TreeMap<VO, List<VO>>` as follows. This code works in *Java 7*:

```java
public static int isEqual(VO a, VO b) {
    if (Math.abs(a.age - b.age) > 2 || Math.abs(a.val - b.val) > 10)
        return 1;
    else if (Math.abs(a.age - b.age) <= 2 && Math.abs(a.val - b.val) <= 10)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VO vo1 = new VO(1, 100);
    VO vo2 = new VO(3, 105);
    VO vo3 = new VO(5, 110);
    VO vo4 = new VO(7, 116);

    List<VO> values = Arrays.asList(vo1, vo2, vo3, vo4);

    Map<VO, List<VO>> buckets = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<VO>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(VO o1, VO o2) {
            return isEqual(o1, o2);
        }
    });

    for (VO vo : values) {
        List<VO> list = buckets.get(vo);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        list.add(vo);
        buckets.put(vo, list);
    }

    // output
    System.out.println(buckets);
    //{VO{1=100}=[VO{1=100}, VO{3=105}], VO{5=110}=[VO{5=110}, VO{7=116}]}
}
```

```java
public static class VO {
    public int age, val;

    public VO(int age, int val) {
        this.age = age;
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "VO{" + age + "=" + val + "}";
    }
}
```